# Array Printing out Process for these lines

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I just want to know the process of how these two lines of code come up with the answer 7.

```
    int[] favNum = {2, 3, 5, 7, 1, 6, 4};
    System.out.println(favNum[favNum[favNum[4]]]);
```

Comment: favNum[4] is "1", so favNum[favNum[4]] is "favNum[1]" and favNum[1] is 3, so favNum[3] is "7".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Analyze this:

**!favNum[4]** selects the value from cell (4) of array favNum so favNum[4]=1;

**!favNum[favNum[4]]** selects the value from cell favNum[4]=1 of array favNum so favNum[favNum[4]]=fanNum[1]=3;

*and so !**favNum[favNum[favNum[4]]]=favNum[favNum[1]]=favNum[3]=7**.

So you start reading this from inside and step by step to outside..

Answer (score 2):

The expression `favNum[favNum[favNum[4]]]` has to be evaluated from inside to outside. Here I start with the innermost and end with the outermost

- favNum[4] -> fifth element of array, 1
- favNum[1] -> second element of array, 3
- favNum[3] -> fourth element, 7